# Form and subform based on same table in MS Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a customers table in an ms access 2010 database including such things as CustomerID, FullName, Address, City, StateProvince, PostalCode, etc.

I want to set up a main form that contains two subforms.  ListSubForm has just a list of FullNames, which the user can filter by typing into a textbox.  DetailSubForm then prints out things like Address, City, StateProvince, PostalCode, etc for the specific customer selected by the user from the filtered list in ListSubForm.

All of the examples I can find on the web are for Master/Detail subforms where the master and detail are two different tables with a one to many relationship.  That is not what I want.  I would like to understand how to set up master/detail subforms based on the same table.  With one subform just giving more detail about the specific record chosen from the first subform.

I want to avoid getting too deep into VBA because I am new to it.  I would prefer something I can set up using simple macros.

Here are the two subforms on the MainForm in Design View:

[image]

Here are the two subforms on the MainForm in Form View:

[image]

And here is the result of clicking the ... button next to the On Current Event in the Property Sheet of ClientListForm:

[image]

Where do I go from here?

EDIT:

I created a split form as per Yawar's suggestion.  It allows the user to select a customer whose data is then shown in more detail at left, but it looks like this:

[image]

The datasheet is ugly, and the datasheet is not filterable, so the user would have to tab through thousands of records.  Is there a way to make it look like it is not a datasheet at left?  Perhaps by not making it a datasheet in the first place?  The continuous form with a textbox filter in my original example above looked fine.  Also, is there a way to make the list of customers at left filterable so that a user can type in a customer's name and then be able to have the list of customers shrunk down to only those with the desired name?

SECOND EDIT:

After Yawar's edit, I followed the combobox instructions again and got the error message again.  Also, there are problems with this approach because it is a drop down list that does not show all the options at once, also the combobox is not filtered like what I showed in my original posting above.  However, I am posting the results as follows.  Here is the error message that comes up, note that the detail info on right does not match the selected client on left:

[image]

Here is the line of code to which you are directed if you click the debug button in the preceding image:

[image]

And for good measure, here is an image of part of the datasheet of the underlying table, to show that the field name is correct:

[image]

THIRD EDIT:

I changed the code to match Yawar's new suggestion, and got the following error message when trying to change the selection of the combobox:

[image]

When I clicked the debug button, it gave me the following:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to do this with Macros. The main idea is you want to filter the second subform based on the record selected in the first subform. A bound form has a Filter property that you can use for this.

Comment: @HK1 Thank you.  How do I set up the two subforms to be bound forms?  I simply created a blank MainForm in design view and dragged the two subforms onto it.  I think I need to do more to hook them together, but I do not know what.

Comment: No, they won't be hooked together or synchronized in design view. You have to use VBA to make them appear to be hooked together. You have to use the First subform's Current Event to set the Filter Property on the Second Subform.

Comment: @HK1 I added two gif files to my original posting above.  Also, I opened ClientsListForm in design view and found the On Current event in the Event tab of the Property Sheet.  I clicked on the ... button, and got a dialog box asking if I want to use Macro Builder, Expression Builder, or Code Builder.  Am I on the right track?  If so, what do I do from this point?

Comment: @CodeMed - you have to use the Code Builder. See my answer. I will add more details if you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need subforms to handle a one-to-one relationship. Put your combo box of full names (let's call it `cmbCustomer`) on the main form. But don't bind it to your underlying `Clients` table. Instead, leave it unbound and fill it with customer full names using its `Data > Row Source` property. You can use a SQL statement in the `Row Source`, like:

```
select distinct FullName, CustomerID
from Clients
order by FullName
```

Make sure the `Data > Bound Column` property is set to `2`. You want the customer ID to be captured in this field. Also make sure `Format > Column Count` is `2`, and adjust some of the widths in the `Format` tab as necessary.

Now fill up the rest of the main form with all the customer table fields, including the customer ID field. This time, bind them all to the underlying data source. A shortcut I use is to just drag and drop the fields from the listing in the `Field List` panel (Design > Add Existing Fields). However, hide the `CustomerID` field (`Format > Visible = No`).

Finally, set a VBA procedure to handle `cmbCustomer`'s `After Update` event by navigating the form to whatever customer ID was just selected in the combo box:

```
Private Sub cmbCustomer_AfterUpdate()
  set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

  rst.FindFirst "CustomerID = " & cmbCustomer
  Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

  set rst = nothing
End Sub
```

Voila, the form will automatically jump to the chosen customer ID whenever you select a new customer from the combo box.

Comment: +1 Thank you. But it's still not functional.  I got a combobox to populate with FullName values, and the other fields I added to the screen fill up with one customer's data.  But the customer identity of the other fields does not change when combobox selection is changed.  Also, my real data has thousands of customers, so a combobox will not work.  My original posting above shows the customer names in a searchable list, so the user can isolate the specific customer they want.  Can you show me how to use that kind of filterable selection list to change the customer in other fields?

Comment: I guess you're trying to implement a master-detail view. Access has built-in support for this. IIRC it's called a split form. I will revise my answer in a few hrs...

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.  I tried to create a split table myself, and I posted a print screen of it as an edit to my original question above.  I have some concerns that I listed above.  Such as the datasheet being ugly and the fact that the datasheet is not filterable.  I elaborated on those concerns in my edit above.  Can you suggest ways to get past those concerns?  This is my first split form, so perhaps the changes that I desire are easy to come by.

Comment: There is a standard way to do what you're describing in your question edit--it's a combo box! :-) It lets you show the full list of customer names, while at the same time filtering it in realtime while you type. A combo box populating with thousands of records from a table will work fine. I'm doing it myself. Your main problem seems to be that you haven't hooked up the combo box selection change event handler. Try using the combo box's `After Update` event. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this again.  I have followed your advice and posted a second edit to my original posting above.  As you can see, it is throwing a specific error message, of which I have posted a print screen.  In addition, the combobox is just a drop down list which does not show multiple customers in its default view, and which is not filterable.  Can you show me how to get past the error message so that it works?  And can you show me how to make something that allows the user to filter names, while showing all the filtered names in the default view, like my original question?

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered the code to jump to the customer chosen in the combo box! I will edit my answer ASAP to show the correct code.

Comment: Thank you again.  I tried your latest code, and it throws an error, which I illustrated with two printscreens in a third edit to my original posting above.  Also, this is still just a drop down menu, which is not what I asked in my original posting above.  Wouldn't it be better to do this with a listbox instead of a combobox?  Can you show me how to get past the error above?  Preferably with a listbox instead of a combobox?

Comment: The problem with your code is that the name of the ID column was not correct, and also, cmbCustomer needs to be something like cmbCustomer.Column(0) in order to tag the id instead of the full name.  Since I figured this out, it works now.  I will therefore mark yours as the answer and move on.

Comment: Yes, the `ID` name was wrong. Good you caught that. But, the instructions I provided (bind column 2 as the combo box value) make it unnecessary to use `Column(0)`. I tested this out.

Answer (score 0):

I know little about Access, but think the following approach is workable: create a detail form and a datasheet form.  Do NOT link them via some key, but when the user clicks a row in the datasheet, pass the key parameter (RecordID) to the detail form and trigger a requery.